# *export ... from* returns undefined in node with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm aggregating files in an `index.ts`. When I try to import from the `index.ts` the object returns as undefined. When I try to import directly from the file, it works fine. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong -- it's my impression that `export { ... } from '...'` should work fine in Node with TypeScript (which is the case for this app).

*fileThatUsesTheExportedVariables.ts*

```
import { dates } from '../consts' // Undefined
import { dates } from '../consts/index' // Undefined
import { dates } from '../consts/dates' // Works
```

*consts/index.ts*

```
export { dates } from './dates'
// ...
export { someNamedExport } from './someFile'
```

*consts/dates.ts*

```
const months = {
  // some months stuff
}

export const dates = {
  months,
  // ...
  someOtherChildObject
}
```

I presume I'm doing something silly. VS Code can connect the dots which makes it all the more frustrating.

Thanks in advance for any and all help

---

---

**UPDATE:** @casieber pointed out it might be helpful to know more about the TS compilation process (uses `tsc`):

---

Versions:

- `tsc` 2.9.1
- `typescript` 6.1.0

---

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": [
    "app/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using ts-node to run, or are you compiling using tsc / other and then running with node? In any case, can you share your ts-node/ts version numbers? What does your tsconfig look like?

Comment: @casieber very relevant questions -- using tsc, updated my original post with tsc and typescript details. Let me know if anything seems to stand out

Comment: What do you mean by "`typescript` 6.1.0", when the latest version of TypeScript is `4.something.something`? And why the versions of `typescript` and `tsc` are different?